# Python trainticket machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am stuck at an excercise, I need to make a train ticket machine but I am just 1 week practicing in Python and I don't know how to start.

First I've got this:

```
stations = ['Schagen', 'Heerhugowaard', 'Alkmaar', 'Castricum', 'Zaandam', 'Amsterdam Sloterdijk','Amsterdam Centraal', 'Amsterdam Amstel', 'Utrecht Centraal', ' ’s-Hertogenbosch', 'Eindhoven', 'Weert', 'Roermond', 'Sittard', 'Maastricht']

begin = input('What is your starting station?: ')
```

but now it needs to check if the input is in stations, if its not it need to print:

```
'This is not a station, your starting station will be: Schagen.'
```

Next step is asking for the final destination. If the final destination is in stations, after that it checks if the final destination has a higher index in the list then the begin station, if not, then print 'Wrong station' (or something like that) and add the last station in the list as final destination.

Next step needs to print the following:
- Name of the starting station

- Name of the destination station
- names of stations which Are passed during the trip
- Price of the trip (per station its like 5 euros.
- and finally a summary;

You get on the train on station:  *beginstation*

Here the names of the stations we pass during our trip like:

-Heerhugowaard

-Alkmaar

You get out of the train in: ...

Could you give me some tips how to think like a programmer so I can realize this, the above exercise is pretty awesome, but very hard if you're just one week in to python/programming ;).

Regards,

Comment: Break it down into smaller tasks and find out how to do each one. For instance how do you check if a string is not present in a list of strings? This is achieved using `if begin not in stations:`. If you step through it you should be able to get it all done.

Comment: I keep getting:   if begin not in stations:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Yes I've got that: if begin not in stations:
        print ('Invalid')

Comment: Look at a basic tutorial about indentation.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356303/compare-values-in-one-list/40356550#40356550 which appears to be about the same piece of course work